# If $X$ is a subset of a group $G$, and $H \le G$, then $X^H \lhd \langle X, H \rangle$ and $X^{ \langle X, H \rangle} = X^H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $X$ is a subset of a group $G$, and $H \le G$, then $X^H \lhd \langle X, H \rangle$ and $X^{ \langle X, H \rangle} = X^H$?

Here $X^H$ we mean the subgroup $\langle x^h = h^{-1}xh \, | \, x\in X, h \in H \rangle$ of $G$.

What I have so far is:

If $x^h \in X^H$ then clearly $x^h=h^{-1}xh \in  \langle X, H \rangle,$ so that $X^H \le  \langle X, H \rangle$. Now to prove normality, I think there are two cases to consider.

1. If $h \in  \langle X, H \rangle$. Then $h^{-1}X^H h= (X^H)^h = X^H.$
2. If $x \in  \langle X, H \rangle$. Then because $x, x^{-1} \in X^H$, it follows that $x^{-1} X^H x = (X^H)^x=X^H$.

Is this correct?

I'm stuck with showing now $X^{ \langle X, H \rangle} \le X^H$. The other side $X^{ \langle X, H \rangle} \ge X^H$ is obvious.

Comment: @relep He defined it to be a subgroup.

Comment: $X^H \unlhd \langle X,H \rangle \Rightarrow X \le N_G(X^H) \Rightarrow (X^H)^X = X^{\langle X,H \rangle} \le X^H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I've forgotten a bit of group theory. Can you please explain how the implication $X \le N_{G}(X^H)$ follows? Thank you.

Comment: Every subgroup normalizes itself, so it is contained in its own normallizer.